# How to typeset nested radical/root expressions?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, root, radicals

I'm writing my own math expression typesetting engine. I want to learn how to best typeset radical expressions. The choices actually apply to all radical expressions, however, nested radical expressions make the visual differences more clear.

1. Flush
   [image]
2. Indent on Left & Right
   [image]
3. Indent on Bottom
   [image]
4. Indent on Left & Right & Bottom
   [image]

Comment: I hope this is used only in displays, otherwise there will certainly be a disruption in the baselines.  that said, although it may not be traditional, i like the effect of (2) and ((4).  (i will seek the opinion of a more skilled math editor, and report if i get an answer.)

Comment: Can we see your MWE to understand better your question, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano are you asking for TeX code? It is not TeX. What's not clear in the question?

Comment: @an0 Why, then, have you ask a question? I have not undersood.

Comment: @Sebastiano 1. It is the most fitting subsite to ask questions about typesetting. I initially planned to post it on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com) but they explicitly prohibit questions about typesetting. 2. It is actually TeX related. The math expression can be converted to TeX code like this `0+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}-4`, however, the math semantics will be lost.

Comment: @an0 Excuse me then. Now I have understood :-).

Comment: I think the question is interesting, but I doubt the question is actually on-topic here because it is mainly about typography as such and not about how to achieve the different appearances in TeX/LaTeX or what would be a consistent typography in the context of a larger LaTeX document. The fact that the expression could be converted to TeX is not really sufficient, you can show, e.g., chessboards in LaTeX but that doesn't mean that a question asking how a chess piece should look is on topic.

Comment: See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/typesetting-and-typography-related-questions with a quote from the answer: _The questions there though should be more about how to achieve certain typographical features in TeX or about TeX-nical typography (e.g. a question about whether to use `:` or `\colon`). More general typography questions are probably "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based" here._

Comment: @Marijn if you are more concerned about the meta of the question, please forget what you read in the original question and image I posted the question like this: "I'm writing a new TeX typesetting engine. I want to learn how to best typeset radical expressions. The choices actually apply to all radical expressions, however, nested radical expressions make the visual differences more clear. So here is the MWE TeX code `0+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}-4`, and below are the 4 typesetting styles. Which one is the best?" Is it now on topic?

Comment: @an0 -- I've now received an opinion from a skilled math editor.  Example (4) is the most "elegant", probably the most quickly understood, but is in a style that very few authors (or current editors) care about.  Version (2) would be more appropriate in-line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! I can see why mathematically prefer style 4. However, contrary to what you said, all the on-line LaTeX engines use style 3 instead of style 2.

Comment: @an0 -- I'm not sure, and don't currently have the ability to test, it may be difficult to achieve (2), because TeX expands vertically only in specific increments.  So it's not surprising that (3) is the default.  Anything else requires explicit attention.

Comment: @an0 it would be marginally on-topic, but still mostly opinion-based, which is one of the official reasons for being off-topic. However, the question would not be genuine, because you are not in fact using TeX syntax and 'building a new Tex typesetting engine' but rather something similar to TeX (cf. MathJax, which is also off-topic). That said, on TeX.SE such questions are not necessarily a problem, often we leave off-topic questions open if they are interesting (and this one is, also shown by the nice discussion between you and @barbarabeeton).